# How do I get rid of the right column on Google News frontpage?

Tags: google-news

I liked Google News frontpage better before when both left and right columns showed different topics. The new layout has all the topics listed on the left column, and on the right it shows stuff I'm not interested in. e.g. World Cup scores, weather, spotlight, fast flip etc.

Can I revert it to the old layout?

Answer (score 2):

How you arrange the boxes is up to you (there's more than one in a column). Just click **edit this page** or **add a section** at the top-right.

To delete or change a section, click the former and then that column. There will be options both to delete it and to edit it.

Comment: I believe what you describe only applied to the old layout. I don't think that works with the new one.

Comment: Yeah it doesn't work with the new layout. I read all the instructions and settings. At this point I'm not sure if it's even possible. (unless i grease monkey it)

Answer (score -1):

In order to change the layout of your google site from multiple columns to one column you need to go to: Edit Page (top right) -->Layout (top left) --> One column (or choose the amount of columns)

Hope this is what you were looking for