# Is there any way to revert to the old Google News home page?

Tags: google-news

Is there any way to revert to the old Google News home page? I was happy with the old layout but I absolutely hate the new layout.

Comment: [Similar](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/1274/how-do-i-get-rid-of-the-right-column-on-google-news-frontpage)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not currently possible to revert to the old layout on Google News, and you are not the only one to request it, as can be seen on the Google [user forums](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/news/label?lid=06c20bed07a04da6&hl=en).

It appears to only have been the US layout which has changed at the moment and a compromise would be to switch to an alternative 'edition' such as the UK, which currently retains the old layout, but that would only mean general "World" news would be applicable, and so this really would cripple your use.

Several people on the Google forums also suggested using alternate news aggregators instead such as [Ask News](http://news.ask.com/news).